# find xpath of label with non breaking space

Tags: xpath, robotframework

I am trying to get xpath for following html code, but nothing seems to be working. I appreciate your suggestion. I need to get the xpath based on text.

```html
<label class="label" securityidpath="ACCOUNTS_FS.PART_ACCOUNT_HEADER_FS.PART_ACCOUNT_STATUS" title="Part Account Status">Part Account Status:&nbsp;
</label>
```

FYI, I tried following variant xpath

1. //label[normalize-space(text())='Part Account Status:\u00a0']
2. //label[normalize-space(text())='Part Account Status:\u000a']
3. //label[normalize-space(text())='Part Account Status:\u202f']

and all the options as per following url https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character

Thank You,
Yougander

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
/label[normalize-space(text())='Part Account Status:&#160;']
```

Or use the hexadecimal variant `&#x00A0;` instead of the decimal `&#160;`.
Also note that XPath uses slashes (and not backslashes) to define paths, so referencing the root node `label` would be done by `/label`. 
The typo `lable` instead of `label` is trivial.

BTW you can avoid the trouble with the entity by using the `title` attribute in your XPath:

```
label[normalize-space(@title)='Part Account Status']
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. There was a typo in my question (actually I used //label while testing, but in hurry i posted it as \\lable). I tried with your suggested xpath. //label[normalize-space(text())='Part Account Status:&#x00a0'] and //label[normalize-space(text())='Part Account Status:&#160'].

Comment: At the moment, no. The second approach also doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

your element name is wrong and change UTF character name as HexaDecimal entity values:

```
//label[normalize-space(text())='Part Account Status:&#x00a0;']
```

XPATH require forward slash